# How to move a file in C

Tags: c, rename

I need to move a file from an input to a certain folder, however, 'rename' keeps crashing the entire application.

```
char start[50]; 
const char dest = "C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds\supertemp.JPG";

printf("Please enter file to move \n");
fgets(start, sizeof(start), stdin);

if (rename(start, dest) == 0){
    printf("Success \n");
}

else{
    printf("Failed %s ", GetLastError());
}
```

It always crashes at ' if(rename(start, dest) ==0)'.

I don't ever get as far as retrieving an error value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Cheers

Comment: `fgets()` keeps the ENTER. You should probably get rid of it, with something like `start[strlen(start) - 1] = 0;`. But this doesn't look like a reason for crashing.

Comment: Ooh good point! Cheers

Comment: Welcome to Windows. Are you sure that `\W`, `\S`, `\o`, `\i` and `\b` are all valid [C escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences), and you need these special characters in the filename? If not, you probably want to double those backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems. You have not declared `dest` as an array, and you need to put a double \\ in a literal string, to prevent \ being used as an escape character.

```
const char dest[] = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\oobe\\info\\backgrounds\\supertemp.JPG";
```

Comment: Did the \\, and changed it to an array - but it still crashes.

Comment: That is because you haven't taken on board @pmg's comment. Without it, my test did not crash, but it failed.

Comment: Crashes what "entire application"? How do you crash "half an application"? What do you mean by "crashes"? Have you isolated this problem to a trivial program?

Comment: Even if you take out the input, and have the variables pre-defined, it still crashes.  By crashes, Windows says 'program has stopped working'.

Comment: You have not posted the complete trivial program, so it's anybody's guess what is wrong.

Comment: This is the complete program, I isolated this bit to see why it wasn't working and still haven't managed to fix it